Why do some of my SQL explicit pass through queries run in SQL Server but not in SAS EG?
As I understand, explicit pass through queries are sent verbatim to the SQL server from SAS.
I have something like:
proc sql;
connect to odbc(dsn = dbname);

execute by odbc(

/* some preceding code here */

drop table if exists workforce;
select * into #full_wf
(
select a,b,c,'blue' as colour
from #table1
union all
select a,b,c, colour
from #table2
) as tbl

);
disconnect from odbc;
quit;

Everything inside the execute by odbc statement runs OK in SQL Server, but in SAS EG it stops at the point where I try to create the table #full_wf. It looks like a fairly harmless query to me.
The SQL code has no "--" style comments which I know will stuff up the code, see (SAS explicit pass-through with --comments converts to single line). So I'm fairly sure that's not the cause.
I have tried writing the result of that union as a permanent table, but nothing gets created. When I run the same code in SQL Server it works.
I've also tried options sastrace to debug, but what is printed to the log looks fine to me, except it is all in one line. I've tried putting a semicolon at the end of the query, and it doesn't work too.
Has anybody encountered something like this before?

What's SQL Server 2018? Are you perhaps thinking of version 18 of the client application, SQL Server Management Studio?

There is no SQL Server 2018 version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022 - so which one are you really using? Run SELECT @@VERSION to find out ....

I'm going to hazard a guess it's using some kind of cursor, which doesn't work well if there is procedural code involved. Why don't you rewrite it as a single query (using CTEs etc)?

SELECT .... INTO ... is a SQL Server specific syntax and does not exists in the ISO Standard SQL. Try with CREATE TABLE table_name AS SELECT ...

I've removed the references to the non-existent version of SQL Server, as it only confuses matters.

When I used to write queries like this I would only ever put one pass-thru SQL statement inside an execute by odbc (); SAS SQL statement, i.e. the code inside the brackets would not contain a semicolon. Try breaking your SQL Server statements into separate exec(); statements?

What make you think the table is not being created?  Since you're using temp tables for the inputs and outputs, they won't exist in SQL Server after SAS disconnects from SQL server, right?  The SQL server session only exists while that EXECUTE statement is running.  In SQL Server Management studio, your session persists so you can see temp tables after a query completes.

If you are going to make temporary tables then make sure you only have one connection to the external database.  The easiest way is to create a libref first and then use that for the explicit pass thru queries:
libname mysql odbc ....;
proc sql;
   connect using mysql;
   execute by mysql ( ... SQL/Server code ...);

When you want to release the connection to the external database you can clear the libref.
libname mysql clear;

